# How to get rid of " " when using fputcsv?

Tags: php, csv

Here´s the relevant snippet of the code:

```
        ... (above this snippet is just variable initialization & such) ...

        // Putting the variables in a list
        $list = array("$val1; $val2; $val3; $val4; $val5");

        // Opening the CSV file
        $file = fopen("tickets.csv","w");

        // Writing the values into the CSV file
        foreach ($list as $line){
        fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));}

        // Close the CSV file.
        fclose($file);
```

The result of the above code is:

```
"Variable1; Variable2; Variable3; Variable4; Variable5"
```

but I want the result to be:

```
Variable1; Variable2; Variable3; Variable4; Variable5
```

because that way, each variable is stored in it´s own column in the CSV excel file. How do I achieve this? Simply removing the ""´s when declaring the array in *$list* the array doesn´t really cut it. Thanks in advance, cheers!

Comment: You accomplish what you want by putting each variable in its own array element int `$list`.  That's how `fputcsv` is supposed to work.  You're getting quotes because it's quoting the string with spaces in it; you never wanted the spaces in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must let `fputcsv()` do the work. Tell it to use `;` as delimiter instead of ','.

```
    $line1 = array("foo", "bar");
    $line2 = array($val1, $val2, $val3, $val4, $val5);

    $list = array($line1, $line2);

    $file = fopen("tickets.csv","w");
    foreach ($list as $line) fputcsv($file, $line, ';');
    fclose($file);
```

Comment: This just gives me a blank CSV file. Here´s my code: http://pastebin.com/DwzG0thB, so you see the variables aren´t empty, since they do also make an entry in a DB. EDIT: It works fine I just didn´t replace the file on the server... I guess that´s a good indicator to take a break. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `trim` function will probably do what you're looking for.

```
fputcsv($file, trim(explode(',',$line), '"'));
```

Comment: foreach ($list as $line){
   fputcsv($file, trim(explode(',',$line), '"'));
   }

this is the loop now and the result is an empty CSV file :(

Comment: I edited the wrong post, sorry about that.  Moving too quickly this morning.